# How to assign a new level to many levels of a categorical variable

Tags: python, categorical-data

I have a model which has many categorical variables. For each categorical variable there are many levels, like 50~. But not all of them have significant counts. I got these counts using the function `value_counts()` in Python:

```
A                 50 
B                 38
C                 26
D                 18
E                 10
...
T                 1
X                 1
Z                 1
```

How can I change the levels with count (say) less than 5 to a new level "others"?

```
for x in data.class:
    if x.value_counts() <30:
        x = "others"
```

Comment: If would be useful if you could provide what the original data look like. It is unclear whether you want to act on the original data frame or on the one that you obtain after the `value_counts()`. In the latter case you could just rename the entries that satisfy your condition: what in particular have you found difficult to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the notation you gave (i.e. `data` is the dataframe and `data.class` is the categorical variable you want to process), this can be done this way:

```
def cut_levels(x, threshold, new_value):
    value_counts = x.value_counts()
    labels = value_counts.index[value_counts < threshold]
    x[np.in1d(x, labels)] = new_value

cut_levels(data.class, 30, 'others')
```

Note that this modifies the original data, thus if you want to keep it, do a copy of it before or change the code to this:

```
def cut_levels(x, threshold, new_value):
    x = x.copy()
    value_counts = x.value_counts()
    labels = value_counts.index[value_counts < threshold]
    x[np.in1d(x, labels)] = new_value
    return x

new_class = cut_levels(data.class, 30, 'others')
```

Comment: Instead of using `np.in1d(x, labels)` it is better to use `x.isin(labels)`. It is way faster.

Answer (score 0):

Say your data is in a DataFrame `df`, and the column of interest is named `column`.

```
treshold = 5 #or whatever value makes sense to you

def set_levels(df):

    for i df.column.unique():
       if len(df.loc[df.column == i]) < treshold:
          df.loc[df.column == i] = 'other'

    return df

new_df = set_levels(df)
```

Comment: @Murtuza_07 Let me know if the solution works. In that case, if you could accept the answer I'd be very thankful.

Comment: What is the purpose of the counter `count`?